# How to pass a search term to Bing from silverlight or google

Tags: silverlight, bing-api, google-search-api

Has anyone had any luck passing from Silverlight to Bing or Google a url parameter based string that will open search results in a browser. I have been using the Bing API and been able to search and return results within the client and I have also done this using JSON and passing values to the Google API. However if you want to just send a query string to either service and have the results returned via a browser result list I have not found this to be possible. What I am trying to see if it is possible to pass a term "gocart" to Google or Bing as a url  (http:www.bing.com/query?gocart) and it return in a new browser window results of the search term. From my initial research both search engines appear to prevent unauthorized queries via URL, I was curious if anyone found it different.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made a hyperlink class:

```
private class HyperlinkButtonWrapper : HyperlinkButton
{
    public void OpenURL(string navigateUri)
    {
        OpenURL(new Uri(navigateUri, UriKind.Absolute));
    }

    public void OpenURL(Uri navigateUri)
    {
        base.NavigateUri = navigateUri;
        base.TargetName = "_blank";
        base.OnClick();
    }
}
```

Then use it like this:

```
private void ButtonSearch_Click(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var hyperlinkwrapper = new HyperlinkButtonWrapper();
    hyperlinkwrapper.OpenURL(@"http://www.google.com/#q=gocart");

}
```

I found that on this [blog](http://blog.falafel.com/blogs/jonathantower/10-11-16/Opening_a_URL_in_a_New_Window_from_Code-Behind_in_Silverlight.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

couldn't test it right now but try:

```
HtmlPage.Window.Navigate(new Uri("http://www.bing.com/query?gocart", UriKind.Absolute), "_blank");
```

This should open a new browser window or tab with the url supplied... wouldn't expect any differences between Google and Bing in this regard.

The MSDN reference link is http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc190508%28v=VS.95%29.aspx

Comment: I had some trouble with this method. It opened the page fine, but it was like I had no search query input. Seems like it ignores the querystring parameters. That occured on some pages and not on all, so you might have not encountered this yet.

Answer (score 0):

If you use google you can get html rendered results using Yahia's suggestion and open a link formatted such as this http://www.google.com/#q=gocart.

Out of the few api options I tried from the search api documentation I could only change the language without entering my API key.
(http://www.google.com/#q=gocart&hl=fr  for French)  Page result size etc failed but if you're looking for something quick and dirty with not much control the above will work.